# Compile multiple C++ files with SublimeText3

Tags: c++, build, compilation, g++

I was using a `.bat` to compile my C++ files but I would like to find a Build System for ST3 who is able to find alone (throught `#include <header.h>` ) which files needs to be compiled

I found some build system who can build your C++ files, but only if you put the right name. In that case that's almost easier to edit the `.bat` file when needed..

Is

```
@echo off
g++ main.cpp function.cpp -o start.exe
start.exe
pause
```

a good g++ syntax?

Do someone have the solution?

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.